# Is it permissible to use a list as the payload in a JWT

Tags: jwt

Some JWT modules (e.g. pyjwt) throw an exception when decoding a JWT where the payload string encodes a list as opposed to a map/dict.  I came across an api that sends such a JWT as a response to request and I need to decode it.  I can use a custom method to decode the JWT, but I'm wondering if the api is going against the JWT protocol by encoding a list as the payload instead of encoding a dict with a key whose value is the list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the JWT RFCs allows anything that's base64 encodable to be used as payload. It doesn't have to be JSON. So it depends on the library you're using.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the RFCs, where I find this, as well as other passages, that suggest the payload not only has to be Json, but should be as set of key-value pairs: "JWTs represent a set of claims as a JSON object that is encoded in a
   JWS and/or JWE structure.  This JSON object is the JWT Claims Set.
   As per Section 4 of RFC 7159 [RFC7159], the JSON object consists of
   zero or more name/value pairs (or members), where the names are
   strings and the values are arbitrary JSON values. "

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I once made a token decoder and used [JWS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515.txt) back then. On page 7 it's written: *(Note that the payload can be any content and need not
   be a representation of a JSON object.)*. But I guess the RFC you linked to is stricter.